# How can i sort two column in my data set i wanna sort by column distance and GoingTo?

Tags: r, sorting, data-science

this is my data set but i converted it to data frame

```
travel <- data.frame(
          date=c("1/6/2012","1/6/2012",
               "1/4/2012","1/4/2012",
               "1/3/2012","1/3/2012","1/2/2012")
          ,GoingTo=c("Home","GSK","Home",
                     "GSK","Home","GSK","Home")
          ,Distance=c("51.29","51.63","51.27",
                      "49.17","51.15","51.80","51.37"))
```

and then i try to write this code to sort two columns but i have this Error .

```
Data_Sort <- travel[sort(travel$Distance,travel$GoingTo , decreasing = TRUE),]
```

Error

```
Error in is.na(na.last) || na.last : invalid 'y' type in 'x || y'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `R`, we need `order` instead of `sort` as `sort` returns the sorted value and not the index, while `order` returns the index which can be used as row index

```
travel[order(travel$Distance,travel$GoingTo , decreasing = TRUE),]
#     date GoingTo Distance
#6 1/3/2012     GSK    51.80
#2 1/6/2012     GSK    51.63
#7 1/2/2012    Home    51.37
#1 1/6/2012    Home    51.29
#3 1/4/2012    Home    51.27
#5 1/3/2012    Home    51.15
#4 1/4/2012     GSK    49.17
```

---

Or in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
travel %>%
      arrange(desc(Distance), desc(GoingTo))
#    date GoingTo Distance
#1 1/3/2012     GSK    51.80
#2 1/6/2012     GSK    51.63
#3 1/2/2012    Home    51.37
#4 1/6/2012    Home    51.29
#5 1/4/2012    Home    51.27
#6 1/3/2012    Home    51.15
#7 1/4/2012     GSK    49.17
```

---

With `sort.int`, there is an option to return `index.return = TRUE` and then extract the `ix` element, but it s not applicable to here as the columns are not of class `integer`

Comment: but 'order ' is it deffrent about sort or no ?

Comment: @M.s411 `v1 <- c(5, 3, 8, 15, -5); sort(v1); v1[order(v1)]`

Comment: It is not different, it is just that `sort` returns the actual sorted values by default and `order` returns the index of order